# Compiler optimizations disabled. Functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, avr

I am working on Firebird 5 module. That has Atmega2560, I am trying to compile this code and getting this warning.

```
(base) pawansrinivas@Pawans-MacBook-Air Experiment-3 % mkdir -p build
(base) pawansrinivas@Pawans-MacBook-Air Experiment-3 % avr-gcc -g -Wall -O0 -mmcu=atmega328p -c Experiment-3.c -o build/Experiment-3.o
In file included from Experiment-3.c:25:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/avr-gcc@9/9.3.0_3/avr/include/util/delay.h:112:3: warning: #warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed" [-Wcpp]
  112 | # warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed"
      |   ^~~~~~~
(base) pawansrinivas@Pawans-MacBook-Air Experiment-3 %
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a trustworthy library suitable for professional applications. Use something else.

Comment: So, enable optimisations & see if it works. Check main `Makefile` for `-O0` and change it to `-O2`.

Comment: So enable at least `-Og`, if you need timing to be accurate.  And use debug builds only for actual debugging if necessary, being aware that delays are probably way too long.

Comment: @Lundin: In order to emit a cycle-exact delay, the code must translate from µs to cycles, which involves arithmetic.  When the compiler cannot fold this and performs arithmetic at runtime, then the delay function does not what it's supposed to do.  And it will cost lots of program memory.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts It's rather the opposite. You set a prescaler in the timer peripheral which divides down the given clock to a certain cycle period and pick a sensible divisor so that a timer period matches the maximum delay you are looking for. In a sensible application you set clock constants and divisors as compile-time constants then used by your program. If you end up calculating stuff like that in run-time, especially on a potato computer like AVR, then you aren't doing it right.

Comment: @Lundin. Using peripherals like timer is completely inappropriate for a bare-metal target  like avr. There is no OS supprt or whatever; `delay_us` et al are just wrappers for `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles` which injects a small sequence with **exactly** the specified number of cycles. A timer interrupt cannot do that. (You cannort have a timer interrupt that delays for, say, 3 cycles because the initialization + ISR respond time)  is already way more than 3 cycles. `delay_us` can do things a timer can't (and vice versa). But when you want to go timer, you'll have to use an OS or do it by hand.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts It's all about what resolution you need and on most ISA, interrupt latency is both deterministic and negligible. If you need the kind of precision that you can't handle even interrupt latency, then you picked the completely wrong MCU anyway.

Comment: @Lundin: The specification of AVR-LibC's delay routines states that it uses `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles`, and that it may use float arithmetic because the compiler will fold it away. So the specification states that no peripherals will be used. That's like it is and specified, I don't get what you are arguing about. Anyway, even *with* timer you'd need arithmetric to convert from time to init values for SFRs.

Comment: The Atmel/Microchip documentation is quite clear on the optimization levels that are required for the various delay functions.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using AVRGCC with avr-libc?

See [<util/delay.h>](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html)

> **In order for these functions to work as intended, compiler optimizations must be enabled**, and the delay time must be an expression that is a known constant at compile-time. **If these requirements are not met, the resulting delay will be much longer (and basically unpredictable)**, and applications that otherwise do not use floating-point calculations will experience severe code bloat by the floating-point library routines linked into the application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable optimizations in the compiler, i.e. invoke `avr-gcc` with flag `-O1` or higher for the `util/delay.h` functions to work correctly (and for the warning to go away).

E.g.:

```bash
$ # with -O0 (same as with -O flag not provided at all)
$ avr-gcc -O0 -mmcu=atmega328p -c ./test.cpp -o ./test.o
In file included from ./src/main.cpp:8:0:
/usr/avr/sys-root/include/util/delay.h:112:3: warning: #warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed" [-Wcpp]
 # warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed"
   ^~~~~~~
$ # with -O1
$ avr-gcc -O1 -mmcu=atmega328p -c ./test.cpp -o ./test.o
$
```

[more on different optimization levels in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Answer (score 0):

================================================================
At Embedded systems we use cross target complier if you use AVR the complier
"`AVR-GCC Toolchain`"

so if you want to use delay function you will include `<avr/delay.h>`
because you use compiler for AVR processor family .

I wish that my unswer help you.

================================================================